# How can I put grains in my bread?

Tags: bread

OK. So I've learned how to make bread. Here is my technique:

Get unbleached, natural, unenriched flour.

Around 4 or 5 PM. Take a large bowl. Mix 3 cups of flour, 1 1/2 cups of water, a small amount of yeast (say, half of one of the "Fleischmann's" packets) and a pinch of salt. Cover with plastic wrap. The next day at 5am, warm oven to 450 F with (say) a casserole dish. Take the mixture out of the bowl and make it into a ball on floured paper. When the oven's hot, put the ball in the casserole dish and cover tightly with foil. After 30 mins remove the foil, give it another 10 minutes to crisp up.  Do this every day for a few weeks. I can make bread!  Result is fantastic.  I prefer a whole grain flour.

OK. So it's great to add either (a) raisins and/or (b) dark chocolate morsels in to the mix. (Seems to be no difference if you mix them through in the morning or at first.) The result is fantastic.

My question. I want to add in some "grains". I love heavy, "German-style" if you will, "multigrain" breads.

1. Do I have to - say - cook - steam? - or something? Hammer? Air? Deep fry? ....  the "grains" first?  *Or do I just put them right in?* What's the deal on that?
2. Is there anything I should *particularly change* when throwing in grains? So, you experts may say something like: "Everyone knows you then need much more yeast" (just an example). Should I be aware of anything like that?
3. Should I mix them at first when I mix the flour/water, or only mix them through in the morning?

Are the "grains" in "multigrain" bread "just sitting there" - as if you'd scattered some diamonds through the bread, there's no chemical difference - or are they affecting the bread?  What's the deal?  How should I take my first step towards that "heavy, multigrain" feel?  Thx

Comment: Merged into the old question, as the new answers looked good.